# What is this CIL code doing? Why is the 3rd step necessary?

Tags: .net, for-loop, cil

In the book I'm reading _Pro C# 2008 and the .NET Platform" there is a chapter on CIL with some code that I am confused about.

[image]

Why is the step highlighted necessary? As I see it, this is what the code is doing.

1. A local integer variable "i" is created  and is initialized to 0 (by virtue of integers are always initialized to 0 if not explicitly assigned a value)
2. (IL_0000) The value of the local variable [0] (which is "i") is loaded onto the stack
3. (IL_0001) Then the value is popped off the stack and assigned to "i" again . . . WHY? "i" is already 0!

Comment: Consider iterator values starting at the default value a "special case". There are several other values that it can start at, including custom types, initialization of several variables, etc...

Comment: Are you agreeing then that that step is redundant/unnecessary for this example?

Comment: Yes, _for this example_. That simple loop can even be done without any local fields at all...

Comment: is there anything missing from the answer you would like to have added?

Comment: @JB: Not in the least. I was just waiting for the required time to expire so I could mark your answer the one that answered my question! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a memory standpoint, you could consider the initialization of i to 0 unnecessary, as the default value of an initialized int32 variable is 0.

However, the compiler is preserving the semantic information of the loop in the source code. The variable i is, after all, assigned to 0 in the for statement, and this information ends up serialized in the IL. It's likely that this statement will be optimized away by the JIT anyway. At least Mono's JIT does so. From the CIL standpoint it makes it easy to see what's happening:

```
.locals init (int32 i)

ldc.i4.0
stloc.0

// i = 0

br.s loop_test

loop_body:
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.1
    add
    stloc.0

    // i = i + 1

loop_test:
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.s  10
    blt.s loop_body

    // i < 10  

ret
```

At the CIL level, a for is basically:

- a pre-tested loop (the condition is tested before the body is first executed, hence the br, an unconditional branch),
- variable initializers before the loop body,
- operations on the initialized variables at the end of the body.

It's quite easy to visually identify the different for elements in the CIL above.

Comment: Ok I see. So this step would be necessary if the for look had set it to a value other than 0. Then it wouldn't be redundant. The compiler just didn't bother to optimize this, it just took the "template" translation from C# to CIL and this is what it got. Sound right?

Comment: Richard: those opcodes don't exist. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Sorry about my comment . . . I didn't type the right opcodes that I meant (I'm going a little cross-eyed from the terse CIL code!), but I get it now. Thanks for all the help!